# How to expand Data Frame to artificially create dates up to the 31st day in each month no matter how many days that month has in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
data = {
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'nps': [8, 8, 7, 7, 5],
    'target': [True, True, False, False, True],
    'nps_score': [0.56, 0.56, 0.6785, 0.6785, 0.44],
    'event_day': ['2023-02-15', '2023-02-22', '2023-06-10', '2023-06-20', '2022-02-11']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

- id - id of client
- event_day - dates of events
- for each id in a given month values in columns: nps, target, nps_score are the same

I need to expand this data frame so as to have dates in event_date for each id from the 1st to the 31st of a given month regardless of how many days that month actually has.

In short, I need to artificially create rows for each id with event_day range from 2022-07-01 to 2023-10-31 so that in each month there are days from 1 to 31 days.

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
id    | nps  | target  | event_day
------|------|---------|----------
1     | 8    | True    | 2023-02-01
1     | 8    | True    | 2023-02-02
1     | 8    | True    | 2023-02-03
...   | ...  | ...
1     | 8    | True    | 2023-02-30
1     | 8    | True    | 2023-02-31
...
```

And the same for rest od id.

Comment: you could probably just create a new dataframe with just these dates, and then do a full join

Comment: could you show me code of your idea, please? :)

Comment: Mark, I totally do not understand your idea, could you present example of your code based on my example data frame from question ? :)

Comment: yeah just a sec! sorry I had a meeting

Comment: just to clarify- do you need them for every month between the earliest date and the maximum date (i.e. the only value in 2022 is in February, so do you just want values for Feb, or for Feb, March, April, May etc.

Comment: @dingaro. Why `nps_score` was removed from your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
# Get unique records from your dataframe: id, nps, target, nps_score and YYYY-MM
uniq = df.assign(event_day=df['event_day'].str[:7]).drop_duplicates()

# Create the DD (01 -> 31 whatever the month)
days = pd.Series([f'-{i:02}' for i in range(1, 32)], name='day', dtype=str)

# Merge with cross join
out = (uniq.merge(days, how='cross')
           .assign(event_day=lambda x: x['event_day'] + x.pop('day')))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    id  nps  target  nps_score   event_day
0    1    8    True       0.56  2023-02-01
1    1    8    True       0.56  2023-02-02
2    1    8    True       0.56  2023-02-03
3    1    8    True       0.56  2023-02-04
4    1    8    True       0.56  2023-02-05
..  ..  ...     ...        ...         ...
88   3    5    True       0.44  2022-02-27
89   3    5    True       0.44  2022-02-28
90   3    5    True       0.44  2022-02-29
91   3    5    True       0.44  2022-02-30
92   3    5    True       0.44  2022-02-31

[93 rows x 5 columns]

>>> uniq
   id  nps  target  nps_score event_day
0   1    8    True     0.5600   2023-02
2   2    7   False     0.6785   2023-06
4   3    5    True     0.4400   2022-02
```

Comment: smart idea using a cross join! +1

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach

```
uniq = df[['id', 'nps', 'target', 'nps_score']].drop_duplicates()

# set range
date_range = pd.date_range(start='2022-07-01', end='2023-10-31')

# combinations of unique records and dates
out = pd.DataFrame([(id, nps, target, nps_score, date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) for id, nps, target, nps_score in uniq.values for date in date_range],
                   columns=['id', 'nps', 'target', 'nps_score', 'event_day'])
```

Comment: ordinarily Anna your answer would be correct, but OP wants incorrect dates, like February 31st -  see OP again